# How to retrieve URL content using JAVA?

Tags: java, android, url

I store the sensor data in a *web page* using GPRS and I want to retrieve this data to display it in an **Android mobile** application but i don't know how.

How can I read the content from a ***URL*** using **JAVA?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

taken directly from the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

Comment: Probably by first studying the HTTP protocol. What do you mean by "the name of a web page"? Beyond that: the only reason why I put up code is because it is very easy to get there. If you have a question beyond that - *you* should put up the code/research results you collected so far. This is not a site where you drop your requirements and other people do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, what I meant is to get certain fields of the web page.

Comment: As said: it seems that you do not understand how HTTP and web pages in general *work*. You have to step back and do some research there. But I appreciate the quick accept. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you can put up a more specific question ;-)